# Make a model that takes list as input and outputs a number in keras

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, tensorflow, keras

I am pretty new to keras and trying to build a model which takes in a list as input and returns a number between 1 and 16 (or 0 and 15, i have 16 classes)

this is my code so far:

```
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.keras.layers.experimental.preprocessing import TextVectorization
from tensorflow.keras import layers
from tensorflow import keras
import tensorflow as tf

vectorizer = TextVectorization(output_mode = "int")

'''
vocab_data = np.array(["In animus fert nova"])

vectorizer.adapt(vocab_data) #wichtig

print(vectorizer(vocab_data))
'''
# 2 Möglichkeiten für die ersten 4 Metren --> 2^4 = 16 verschiedene Hexameter
num_Hexameter = 16

inputs = keras.Input(shape = (None,1), dtype=tf.int64)
x = layers.Dense(30)(inputs)
x = layers.Dense(20)(x)
x = layers.Dense(15)(x)
x = layers.Dense(10)(x)
x = layers.Dense(5)(x)
outputs = layers.Dense(num_Hexameter, activation = "softmax")(x)

model = keras.Model(inputs = inputs, outputs = outputs)

model.summary()

model.compile(optimizer = keras.optimizers.RMSprop(learning_rate=1e-3),
    loss=keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(), metrics=["accuracy"])

test_train_data_raw = np.array([["In nova fert animus mutatas dicere formas"], 
["corpora di coeptis nam vos mutastis et illas"], 
["adspirate meis primaque ab origine mundi"],
["ad mea perpetuum deducite tempora carmen"]])
vectorizer.adapt(test_train_data_raw)
test_train_data = vectorizer(test_train_data_raw)
test_train_data_lbl = np.array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3],[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 10], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2]])
test_train_data_lbl = np.array([3, 7, 10, 2])
print(test_train_data_lbl.shape)
history = model.fit(test_train_data, test_train_data_lbl, batch_size = 2, epochs = 10)

print(history.history)
test = vectorizer(np.array([["In nova fert animus mutatas dicere formas"]]))
print(test)
print(model.predict(test).shape)
```

the problem is if i leave the line `test_train_data_lbl = np.array([3, 7, 10, 2])` uncommented it will give me the error: `ValueError: Shape mismatch: The shape of labels (received (2, 1)) should equal the shape of logits except for the last dimension (received (2, 8, 16))`

commenting the line leads to no error, but the result of `model.predict(test)` will be an array with shape `(1, 7, 16)`. I understand that the 7 comes from the 7 words i have and 16 from the number of classes but i need this to be of the shape `(1, 16)` so that i can predict which class the line will be in.

I also now that i have to less training data, but i first wanted to make the model work without errors before generating the training data.

Comment: what is the last activation number, is it 16 or 4? why choose `linear` activation if the categorical loss is chosen?

Comment: The last activation number is 16 because i have 16 different classes. I first had softmax but because it didn't work there i googled and some answers said that you might need linear activation. Thats why i switched it. (to test)